# Ubuntu Music @ Android: 404

Tags: android, music

I have created an Ubuntu One Account today and bought some music. Trying to log in this account with the android app on my Motorola Defy (Cyanogenmod 7.2) results in two error messages:

`"Credentials problem. Please try again"`

Followed by:

`"Auth error: Communiction with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 404 (NOT FOUND)"`.

I wasn't able to even provide any credentials yet. Is this a known problem? Any workarounds? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, kudos on a cool phone ( I had the MotoDefy for quite a while - learned a lot about rooting and modding with that phone - really miss it sometimes...)

As to your issue: 
It sounds like a permissions problem related to your CM7 Android and not an Ubuntu or Ubuntu One issue.  Have you tried booting into recovery and using the "fix permissions" option?  You also might try going into settings -> apps and choosing ubuntu one  then clear data.  Then reboot your phone and try to load the app again.

You may have to do all those things in different order and try, try again.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Radix. Unfortunately the steps you mentioned didn't help no matter of the order I applied them in.

The second error message states a 404 error. Is there maybe an issue with the endpoint URL set in the app?

Comment: Are you able to access your Ubuntu one account on your PC or other devices?  If so, you may want to check the XDA forums (they focus on android dev) and see if other people have dealt with this and can offer any solutions. Keep digging, it's a good opportunity to learn and better understand how both your phone and this service work.